# Are “connaître” and “savoir” used properly here?

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

I know that there have been many questions about *connaître* and *savoir*, but it's hard for me to know if their answers apply to my question here.

A friend emailed a joke about a phone call to a hospital.  The caller repeats the following request to a number of people:

> Bonjour ! C'est la réception ? J'aimerais parler avec quelqu'un à propos d'un patient qui se trouve chez vous.  J'aurais souhaité
>   connaître son état de santé, savoir s'il va mieux ou si ... son
>   problème s'est aggravé.

It's really the use of *connaître* that puzzles me here.  It seems strange to me because *son état de santé* feels like a fact, the sort of thing that I want to use *savoir* with.

Would it be incorrect to say *je veux savoir son état de santé*?

I suspect that there are grammatical constraints at work: for example, I'm pretty sure that one couldn't use an embedded sentence with *connaître* (e.g., *je connais qu'il va mieux*).

Answer (score 6):

It would be incorrect to say *savoir son état de santé* just like indeed *connaitre qu'il va mieux* would be.

Native French never confuse these verbs but doing it is a common mistake from French learners.

See for example this [page](https://lingua.ly/blog/difference-between-connaitre-and-savoir/) for some clues about when to use one or the other.

Comment: Awesome link ! The only sentence which sounds odd is "Je sais les noms de tous les rois.". I would say "Je connais les noms de tous les rois" or "Je sais réciter le nom de tous les rois"...

Comment: You are correct, *Je sais les noms de tous les rois* is dated. We wouldn't use it nowadays outside in a literary, very formal context.

Comment: Yes, good link, but I still find *connaître* #4 (*being informed of something’s value*) and *savior* #2 (*information you know/are aware of*) confusing and difficult to distinguish.

Comment: @zabouti indeed, e.g. *je connais l'heure de départ de notre train* but *je sais à quelle heure notre train part*...

Comment: Yes, doing so is a common mistake made by learners of French.

Answer (score 3):

**Connaître est transitif:**

> Je connais cette histoire, je connais cette personne, ...

**Savoir peut s'employer de plusieurs manières:**

- de manière intransitive: *je sais.*
- avec une relative: *je sais **que** je viendrai, je sais **qui** c'est je sais **quand** c'est arrivé.*
- avec un COD de type pronom impersonnel: *je sais ça, je sais cela, je le sais.*
- **moins fréquemment**, avec un COD de type substantif, on emploie en France plus souvent **connaître**: *je sais son nom = je connais son nom, je sais cette histoire = je connais cette histoire.*

Comment: Que veut dire "COD"?

Comment: Et merci pour les examples ou l'on peut utilizer l'un ou l'autre.

Comment: @zabouti - COD = complément d'objet direct

Comment: I think that English would just say "direct object"  but that would not be the same I don't think, because you mean a noun or pronoun, not, say, a dependent clause.  Anyway, thanks for the answer!